# Изменить текст JGrowl уведомления (CMS ModX Revo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modx, popup, уведомления

Здравствуйте, подскажите где изменить текст JGrowl уведомления? CMS ModX Revo. В словарях копал, не нашел именно это уведомление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, разрешилась ли проблема, но неплохо было бы указать, в каком плагине, использующем jGrowl, вы хотите поменять уведомления.
Вот пример того, как это можно сделать в AjaxForm:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    AjaxForm.Message.success = 
    function(message, sticky) {
        if (message) {
            $.jGrowl(message, {theme: 'taleby-message-success', sticky: true});
        }
    }; 
});
```

или ловить событие af_complete

```
$(document).on('af_complete', function(event, response) {
    response.message='';
    if (response.success) { //Если форма заполнена и нет ошибок
        //вызвать свое уведомление,попап или еще что-то.
    }
});
```

Для MiniShop2

```
$(doсument).on('ready', function() {
    miniShop2.Message = {
        success: function() {},
        error: function() {},
        info: function() {},
    };
});
```